# What is the most general statement one can make about roots in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, roots, real-numbers

Baby Rudin Theorem 1.21 says the following:

> For every real $x>0$ and every integer $n>0$ there exists a unique positive real $y$ such that $y^n = x$.

Essentially, this theorem tells us that every positive (trivially we could modify this to say nonnegative since the 0 case is easy) real has a unique positive real as an $n$th root. My question is, how do we modify or generalize this? From familiarity with the reals before making things rigorous (as in Baby Rudin), we can say for example that negative numbers have a unique $n$th root if $n$ odd. I'm sure there are other statements about roots that might be of interest and which I am missing here.

Thus my question is, **what is the general theorem which captures all of these theorems under one rubric as special cases**? Presumably this general theorem makes claims about existence and uniqueness as appropriate. It also seems likely to me that the general statement is actually in $\mathbb{C}$? At any rate, that the statement would make claims about existence and uniqueness are (I think) the key criteria which I am looking for in said theorem.

Comment: There is an important difference between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. If you are working with $\mathbb{C}$, then the fundamental theorem of algebra states that _any (single variable) non-constant polynomial has a root_. But this does not generalize your original statement, since it assumes we are working with the reals. So extending it to $\mathbb{C}$ is essentially saying "let's make up a number $i$ which enables us to generalize the claim". The generalization you are seeking is probably not in $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: There is a "reals-only" version of the fundamental theorem of algebra, namely "Every single-variable polynomial over the reals factors as a product of *at-worst-quadratic* polynomials." This immediately gives that over $\mathbb{R}$ every odd-degree polynomial has a zero. And if we additionally add the statement "Every nonnegative real has a square root," we wind up with a complete picture of polynomial solvability over the reals. Is this the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think so. I guess the general theme of your answer is that the question I refer to is really a question about the solvability of polynomial functions over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @EE18 I would say *factorability* rather than *solvability* (despite not saying that in my previous comment :P), but yes. One way to describe the situation is that we have a perfectly-adequate-but-a-bit-messy theorem in the reals for which the extension to $\mathbb{C}$ provides a more satisfying explanation/interpretation.

Comment: See also the notion of a [real closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, we can describe how (single-variable) polynomials factor over $\mathbb{R}$ completely via the following two facts:

- Every polynomial factors into *at-worst-quadratic* factors.
- For every real number $r$, exactly one of $r$ and $-r$ has a square root.

This is the "reals-only" equivalent of the fundamental theorem of algebra. Part of the compelling beauty of $\mathbb{C}$, though, is the clarity it provides (via the FTA as usually stated) in contrast to the above principle which in contrast seems a bit ad hoc. Yes, the latter is sufficient if you just want to look at the real numbers, but in some sense it's not the "right" story.

More broadly, I think you're looking for the notion of a [real closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field).